# is_customize_preview() like function to check if Customizer "Live Preview" in JavaScript

Tags: functions, theme-development, customization, themes, jquery

Is there a predefined JavaScript function that can be use to check whether the site is being previewed in the Customizer which returns `true` if it is or `false` if it's not, just like what [is_customize_preview() PHP function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_customize_preview/) doing?

```
if (is_customize_preview()) {
    // Script for Customizer Live Preview
}
```

If there's no such predefined function then how can I check if the site is being previewed in the Customizer, in JavaScript?

Comment: Can you give a scenario when this would be necessary?

Comment: @jami0821 If Live Preview then include this block, if not then the other one.

Comment: I mean what scenario would you need to add conditional content to your theme when viewed in the customizer? The purpose of the customizer is to display the theme as it would appear live.

Comment: @jami0821 I want to include that kind of conditional function if any, inside my JavaScript function, right now I can't tell the exact scenario because I'm still finding something.

Answer (score 1):

you can just check for the customize object, but if you absolutely need a conditional statement to determine whatever it is you need, you can do something like this:

```
jQuery( function( $ ) {

    // set var
    var in_customizer = false;

    // check for wp.customize return boolean
    if ( typeof wp !== 'undefined' ) {
        in_customizer =  typeof wp.customize !== 'undefined' ? true : false;
    }

    // if you're in the customizer do this
    if ( in_customizer ) {
        console.log('in customizer');

    // if you're not in the customizer do this
    } else {
        console.log('not in customizer');
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check if you are in an `<iframe>` then check if the `window.parent` has the `wp.customize` properties.

```
// Bool conditional
const isCustomizePreview = () => {
    let isIFrame = (window === window.parent),
    isParentCustomizer = (typeof window.parent.wp.customize !== 'undefined');
    return (isIFrame && isParentCustomizer) ? true : false; 
}
```

Then later in code use it like the php function and like Tim was above:

```
...
  // This is the Customize Preview
    if ( isCustomizePreview() ) {
        console.log('in customizer');

    // This is not the Customizer Preview
    } else {
        console.log('not in customizer');
    }
...
```